# File checked out to 'another user'

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm writing a client application that uses the SharePoint 2010 COM.

A user can download files by just clicking the link (http://[SPserver]/[doclibrary]/[linktoFile]).

With this method, a user can perform a check out or in on a file. But when the user checks the file out in Word and he doesn't check it in before closing, he can't perform a check-in again when re-downloading the file.

: test.docx is locked for editing
by 'another user'

Does anyone know a workaround or a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try SPFile.UndoCheckOut

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.undocheckout.aspx

There is example in powershell using web service:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/7676/undo-the-check-out-of-a-file-from-sharepoint-2010-document-l.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I fixed problem using Squadron > Explorer > Undo Check out

http://www.sharepointcto.com/Squadron/Default.aspx